# pouchDB filtering replication based on logic

Tags: javascript, couchdb, pouchdb

I am trying to figure out how the filter works.

My goal is to exclude documents with a `type` of **user_submits** and only grab the documents with `type` **form** that was created less than a month ago.

Am I doing this right? Do I just return `doc` if all my needs are met?

```
local_db.replicate.from(remote_db, {
  filter: function (doc) {
      if(doc.type == 'form')
        if(doc.created >= (Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)-2419200))
          return doc;
      else if(doc.type !== 'user_submits') return doc;
  }
}).on('complete', function () {
  console.log("success");
})
.on('error', function (err) {
  console.log("error");
});
```

I only ask this because the only example I see for filtering is something like the following and I'm confused on the logic behind it.

```
filter: function (doc) {
  return doc.type === 'marsupial';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A filter function return true of false. It returns true if the document should be replicated. Otherwise false.